# PWA manifest.json start_url failed

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

[in this article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest), "start_url" seems can't use other url. For example, the landing page is '/hello/a.html', I specify the "start_url" to '/hello/b.html', but when I launch the PWA app, the page is still "/hello/a.html"

Comment: What declares that the landing page is '/hello/a.html'? and show us what you have in your manifest.json

Comment: suppose the current page is '/hello/a.html', and have a manifest.json, it contains "start_url", and the value is "/hello/b.html". But when the page is installed, the PWA url still is "/hello/a.html". Manifest.json as following:


{
  "name": "hello",
  "icons": [...]，
  ”start_url“: "/hello/b.html",
  "display": "standalone"
}

Comment: Oh i see, the start_url is the url/route that the installed PWA goes to when launched as an app, so it does not affect the website or the installation, Only when the app is installed and is launched from the app menu does the start_url take effect